# What is this syntax description language describing? Does it have a name or a standard?

Tags: syntax, documentation

I was reading about flexboxes on [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/) and came across this

```
flex: none | [ <'flex-grow'> <'flex-shrink'>? || <'flex-basis'> ]
```

Is there a name for this particular style of syntax? Is there a standard? How is one supposed to interpret it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a slightly modified [BNF, Backus-Naur Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form). This diagram specifically says the `flex` property is either blank (`none`) or has a `flex-grow` property, an optional `flex-shrink` (that's the `?` at the end), and/or there is a `flex-basis`.